# question related to a $\sigma$-finite measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be $\sigma$-finite measure on $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$, and let $D:=\{x:\mu(\{x\})>0\}$, prove that $D$ is countable.

I can only do it when $\mu$ is finite, since $D = \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$, where $A_n = \{x:\mu(\{x\})>1/n\}$ is finite for each $n$.

Comment: Then use the fact that D is the union of the sets D for mu restricted to larger and larger subsets of R with finite measures, and that any countable union of finite sets is at most countable.

Comment: @Did why don't you write this as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can only do it when μ is finite...

Then use the fact that D is the union of the sets D for μ restricted to larger and larger subsets of $\mathbb R$ with finite measures, and that any countable union of finite sets is at most countable.